Which quadratic form does the solution of Ax=b minimizes when A is singular
Suppose $A$ is a positive definite matrix. Then, it is well known that solving $Ax = b$ is equivalent to minimizing the quadratic form $L(x)=\frac{1}{2}x^TAx-x^Tb$. The proof is simple. Suppose $x$ is a solution of $Ax = b$, and $y$ is another vector of the same dimension as $x$. Then,
\begin{equation}
\tag{1}
L(y) - L(x) = \frac{1}{2}y^TAy - y^Tb + \frac{1}{2}x^TAx - x^Tb = \frac{1}{2}(y-x)^TA(y-x)
\end{equation}
Since $A$ is positive definite, Eq. (1) is always non-negative, and $L(y) = L(x)$ if and only if $y = x$. This completes the proof.
In the context of soild mechanics and finite element method, a positive definite $A$ represents linear elastic materials, which can balance whatever external loads (which is $b$) that is acting on it by deformation (the unknown $x$ represents displacements, and $A$ is then the stiffness matrix resembling the stiffness of a spring). But in reality, most materials are plastic. This makes $A$ not positive definite and even singular. For example, a slope has a maximum bearing capacity. When the loads are too large, it collapses. Therefore, for some external load $b$, the force balance equaiton $Ax=b$ would not have solution. This means $A$ is not even full rank.
My question is, for the equation $Ax=b$ with a singular $A$, can we write an equivalent quadratic form that the solution minimizes?
This question is concerned about the application of Lagrange multiplier in nonlinear finite element method. In linear cases, to add a constrant, say $Cx = d$, to the equation $Ax = b$ is routinely done by transforming both equations as minimizing the quadratic form $L(x, \lambda)=\frac{1}{2}x^TAx-x^Tb + \lambda^T (Cx - d)$, where $\lambda$ is the Lagrange multiplier. It can be proven that the equivalence is true for linear elastic materials. But many people also use this technique for plastic materials without reasoning. The legitimacy of such treatment for plastic material seems not obvious to me. Can anyone give me a hint? Thanks.

I don't think people are just pulling some optimization problem out of nowhere in the context of nonlinear finite elements. They add the Lagrange multiplier term to the weak form, which we have before we even write down a linear system. The weak form can often be written in terms of the gradient of some functional and that is what is used

@whpowell96 Yes, that is what I'm confused about. I saw in a lot of finite element textbooks about how this can be done, but no one told me why this can be done. I'm struggling to understand why solving a set of nonlinear PDEs with constraints is equivalent to adding a Lagrange term of the latter to the former. I saw proof for linear cases, but that proof seems to be invalid in nonlinear cases, because it assumes a constant and positive definite stiffness matrix. Can you explain a little bit more if you are familiar with this field?

I think you would need to make another question with a specific PDE or family of PDEs in mind. Not much can be said in general
